# Templated cyclical data structure that works with STL built in functions possible?

Tags: c++, templates, data-structures, iterator, std

Is it possible to create a templated data structure, that is analogous to a cyclic group from Abstract Algebra (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_group), and follows the style of other STL data structures?

The underlying storage should behave like `std::vector<>`, and it should work with a *bidirectional iterator*. The most important requirement, is that it plays nicely with everything else STL-related, especially in `<algorithm>`.

The problem that is foresee is the `end()` iterator. I want `++` and `--` to cause the iterator to wrap around, i.e., addition and subtraction `mod n`, but that would break something like `std::for_each`.

One possibility, that comes to mind, is to use a `bool` flag in the iterator, to indicate a complete traversal from `0 → n - 1`. Any suggestions or comments regarding feasibility would be appreciated.

Comment: What about exposing both the cyclic `begin()`/`end()` as well as the underlying container's `underlying_begin()`/`underlying_end()`. Of course the user needs to know if they want the single-pass or infinite iterator versions when they acquire the iterators originally.